# Altered Dorian scale ( Misheberak scale or Ukrainian Dorian scale)

Tags: piano, chords, scales, modes

First of all, thanks to everyone for this great web site .

I have a question about Altered Dorian scale (Misheberak scale,Ukrainian Dorian scale)

- C Altered Dorian Scale :   C D Eb F# G A Bb.
- A Altered Dorian Scale :   A B C D# E F# G.

But i cant find scales for other keys on internet.

Could someone write me  how would be this scales ,

- B Altered Dorian Scale = ?
- C# Altered Dorian Scale = ?
- D Altered Dorian Scale = ?
- D# Altered Dorian Scale = ?
- E Altered Dorian Scale = ?
- F Altered Dorian Scale = ?
- F# Altered Dorian Scale = ?
- G Altered Dorian Scale = ?
- G# Altered Dorian Scale = ?

Thanks you so much , i'll so glad

I just searched scales for scary and dark composing.  Altered Dorian Scale ( Misheberak scale or Ukrainian Dorian scale) is really good for my hears to compose.

Answer (score 7):

The C and A Altered Dorian scales you show, are simply [Dorian Modes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dorian_mode) with fourth [degrees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(music)) raised by a [Semitone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semitone). So, to work out the Altered Dorians starting on the other pitches: firstly, work out the Dorian modes starting on each of these pitches; secondly, raise the fourth degree of each of these modes by a semitone.

There are two easy ways to work out the Dorian Mode (or scale) starting on any particular pitch:

- use the notes of the Major scale (and so, major [key signature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_signature)) two semitones below the root of your Dorian. For instance, B Dorian has the same notes as A Major, as A is two semitones lower than B (B-Bb-A). A Major has a key signature of three sharps: F#, C# and G#. So the notes of A Major are A-B-C#-D-E-F#-G#. These notes, starting on B, give B Dorian: B-C#-D-E-F#-G#-A. If you then raise the fourth degree by a semitone, you get your Altered Dorian: B-C#-D-E#-F#-G#-A.
- follow the pattern of T-S-T-T-T-S-T between consecutive degrees of the mode (scale), where T is a [Tone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Major_second) (equal to two semitones) and S is a Semitone. To give another example, E Dorian has: E-F#-G-A-B-C#-D, as E-F# is a tone, F#-G is a semitone, and so on. Again, you then raise the fourth degree to get your Altered Dorian: E-F#-G-A#-B-C#-D.

EDIT: Here are each of the scales you asked for...

- **B Altered Dorian**: B-C#-D-E#-F#-G#-A
- **C# Altered Dorian**: C#-D#-E-Fx-G#-A#-B
  (Fx is F [Double Sharp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharp_(music)), so this scale would be better [spelled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enharmonic) as
  **Db Altered Dorian**: Db-Eb-Fb-G-Ab-Bb-Cb)
- **D Altered Dorian**: D-E-F-G#-A-B-C
- **D# Altered Dorian**: D#-E#-F#-Gx-A#-B#-C# (this would be better spelled as **Eb Altered Dorian**: Eb-F-Gb-A-Bb-C-Db)
- **E Altered Dorian**: E-F#-G-A#-B-C#-D
- **F Altered Dorian**: F-G-Ab-B-C-D-Eb
- **F# Altered Dorian**: F#-G#-A-B#-C#-D#-E
- **G Altered Dorian**: G-A-Bb-C#-D-E-F
- **G# Altered Dorian**: G#-A#-B-Cx-D#-E#-F# (this would be better spelled as **Ab Altered Dorian**: Ab-Bb-Cb-D-Eb-F-Gb)
- **Bb Altered Dorian**: Bb-C-Db-E-F-G-Ab (**A# Altered Dorian** doesn't really make sense, as A# Dorian is the same as G# Major, which is a key used in theory but little in practice, as it has six sharps and a double-sharp - Ab Major is used instead, as it has four flats)

Two further things to note:

- when writing out diatonic scales and modes, and those which are alterations of a diatonic mode, such as this one, you should use each letter name *once*, adjusting with [accidentals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accidental_(music)) where necessary.
- the Altered Dorian scale appears to be the fourth mode of the [Harmonic Minor scale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_scale#Harmonic_minor_scale). In other words, each Altered Dorian has the same notes as the Harmonic Minor scale starting on a root seven semitones higher. Or, another way to think of this: if you start playing a Harmonic Minor scale from its fourth degree, you get an Altered Dorian.

Comment: Well done, Bob. Well beyond the call of duty! +2 deserved...

Comment: Too kind, too kind...

Comment: Thank you so much Bob Broadley. I don't know to say Thank but you really teached me so much thing today .

Comment: No problem. Have fun with using these scales!

Comment: Dear Bob ,  the Altered Dominant scale and the Altered Dorian Scales are same right ?

Comment: Oops! No I didn't mean to write that; I'll change it.

Comment: @Alter: Note that this scale is simply the fourth mode of harmonic minor, i.e., A dorian #4 = E harmonic minor, etc. Since it's probably much easier to find a list of harmonic minor scales, this might be the easier path ...

Comment: Last question about it ...   Fx (F double sharp)  means  G ?   What means  Fx - I should play G note  for Fx ?

Comment: Yes, on piano, Fx and G are the same note.

Answer (score 0):

The Mishberak scale is more appropriately called the 4th mode of the minor harmonic. Play any minor harmonic, go to the 4th note, and start your scale there. Altered Dorian is clumsy. But if you want to think of the Mishberak that way, it's just the Dorian mode with a sharp 4.